# DictionaryBase and subclassed object methods

Tags: c#, class, methods, class-design

I am using DictionaryBase for collecting objects.  But I am unable to obtain subclass (HardDrive.cs )methods only the superclass, abstract, DeviceInfo methods such as .Named();

Class HardDrive:DeviceInfo

```
deviceCollection = DictionaryBase
```

I am trying to using HardDrive methods such as Freespace, Size, etc

e.g.
It worked:

```
deviceCollection["Western Digital"].Named(); // Superclass method: Named
```

It doesn't work:

```
deviceCollection["Western Digital"].Size(); // Subclass method: Size
```

I do not know what is possible, is it able to convert to subclass or so?

Thanks kindly in advance.

Filename: DeviceInfo.cs

```
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestHarnessHardDrives
{
  public abstract class DeviceInfo
  {
    protected string name;

    public string Name
    {
      get
      {
        return name;
      }
      set
      {
        name = value;
      }
    }

    public DeviceInfo()
    {
      name = "The device with no name";
    }

    public DeviceInfo(string newName)
    {
      name = newName;
    }

    public void Named()
    {
      Console.WriteLine("{0} has been named.", name);
    }
  }
}
```

Filename: HardDrive.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TestHarnessHardDrives
{
  class HardDrive: DeviceInfo
  {
    // properties
    private ulong _size;
    private ulong _freespace;
    private string _volumeSerialNumber;
    private string _filesystem;

    //methods

    // VolumeName + Caption
    public HardDrive(string newName, ulong newSize): base(newName)
    {
      _size = newSize;
    }

    // Freespace
    public ulong Freespace
    {
      get
      {
        return _freespace;
      }
      set
      {
        _freespace = value;
      }
    }

    // Size
    public ulong Size
    {
      get
      {
        return _size;
      }
      set
      {
        _size = value;
      }
    }

    // VolumeSerialNumber
    public string VolumeSerialNumber
    {
      get
      {
        return _volumeSerialNumber;
      }
      set
      {
        _volumeSerialNumber = value;
      }
    }

    // Filesystem
    public string Filesystem
    {
      get
      {
        return _filesystem;
      }
      set
      {
        _filesystem = value;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

filename: Devices.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TestHarnessHardDrives
{
    class Devices: DictionaryBase
    {
        public void Add(string newID, DeviceInfo newDevice)
        {
            Dictionary.Add(newID, newDevice);
        }

        public void Remove(string newID, DeviceInfo oldDevice)
        {
            Dictionary.Remove(oldDevice);
        }

        public Devices()
        {
        }

        public DeviceInfo this [string deviceID]
        {
            get
            {
                return (DeviceInfo)Dictionary[deviceID];
            }
            set
            {
                Dictionary[deviceID] = value;
            }

        }

        public new IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
        {
            foreach (object device in Dictionary.Values)
                yield return (DeviceInfo)device;
        }
    }
}
```

....main program

```
Filename: Program.cs
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TestHarnessHardDrives
{
    class Program
    {
        public static Devices deviceCollection = new Devices();

        static void getHardDrives()
        {
            string keyHDDName;

            try
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
                "SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk");

                deviceCollection.Add("Western Digital", new HardDrive("Western Digital",100000));

                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    if (queryObj["Description"].Equals("Local Fixed Disk"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Description: {0}", queryObj["Description"]);

                        keyHDDName = queryObj["VolumeName"].ToString() + " "
                                    + queryObj["Caption"].ToString();

                        deviceCollection.Add(keyHDDName, new HardDrive(keyHDDName, 100000));

                    };

                    //     Console.WriteLine("FileSystem: {0}", queryObj["FileSystem"]);
                    //     Console.WriteLine("FreeSpace: {0}", queryObj["FreeSpace"]);
                    //     Console.WriteLine("Size: {0}", queryObj["Size"]);
                    //     Console.WriteLine("VolumeSerialNumber: {0}", queryObj["VolumeSerialNumber"]);
                }

            }

        //      deviceCollection.Add(new SystemInterface("Western Digital"));

            catch (ManagementException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message);
            }
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Create an Array type Collection of DeviceInfo " +
                                    "objects and use it");

            getHardDrives();

            foreach (DeviceInfo myDevices in deviceCollection)
            {
                myDevices.Named();
                myDevices.GetType();
            }

            deviceCollection["Western Digital"].Named();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have more code that goes in the `Devices` class, you don't really need it -- you can just use `Dictionary<DeviceInfo>`.

The requirement in the `getHardDrives()` method seems to be to extract only the hard drives from the dictionary of devices.

Given an `IDictionary<DeviceInfo>`, you can use this line to get the hard drives:

```
var hardDrives = devices.Values.OfType<HardDrive>();
```

This will give you `IEnumerable<HardDrive>`.

If you want both the key and value from the dictionary:

```
var hardDrivesAndIds = devices.Where(x => x.Value is HardDrive);
```

This will give you `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, DeviceInfo>>`.

Another alternative:

```
var hardDriveDictionary = devices.Where(x => x.Value is HardDrive).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value);
```

This will give you `Dictionary<string, DeviceInfo>`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what generics are for. Inherit from Dictionary instead of DictionaryBase. Then, everything you add and remove from the collection will be typed as HardDrive. BETTER YET, you don't even need to inherit ... just instantiate a Dictionary. Like this ...

```
var devices = new Dictionary<string, HardDrive>();

devices.Add("Western Digital", new HardDrive("WesternDigital"));
devices.Add("Seagate", new HardDrive("Seagate"));
```

So your main program would look like this:

```
    namespace TestHarnessHardDrives
{
    class Program
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, HardDrive> deviceCollection = new Dictionary<string, HardDrive>

        static void getHardDrives()
        {
            string keyHDDName;

            try
            {
                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2",
                "SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk");

                deviceCollection.Add("Western Digital", new HardDrive("Western Digital",100000));

                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    if (queryObj["Description"].Equals("Local Fixed Disk"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Description: {0}", queryObj["Description"]);

                        keyHDDName = queryObj["VolumeName"].ToString() + " "
                                    + queryObj["Caption"].ToString();

                        deviceCollection.Add(keyHDDName, new HardDrive(keyHDDName, 100000));

                    };

                    //     Console.WriteLine("FileSystem: {0}", queryObj["FileSystem"]);
                    //     Console.WriteLine("FreeSpace: {0}", queryObj["FreeSpace"]);
                    //     Console.WriteLine("Size: {0}", queryObj["Size"]);
                    //     Console.WriteLine("VolumeSerialNumber: {0}", queryObj["VolumeSerialNumber"]);
                }

            }

        //      deviceCollection.Add(new SystemInterface("Western Digital"));

            catch (ManagementException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " + e.Message);
            }
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Create an Array type Collection of DeviceInfo " +
                                    "objects and use it");

            getHardDrives();

            foreach (DeviceInfo myDevices in deviceCollection)
            {
                myDevices.Named();
                myDevices.GetType();
            }

            deviceCollection["Western Digital"].Named();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

*NOTE: Everything I've written so far only applies if you want a collection with nothing but HardDrives in it. If you have some other kind of device that also inherits from your base Device class, but has its own methods, then generics alone are not enough to solve your problem. At that point, you can store everything as a collection of type Device, and use type-checking to cast it up to its full type, or you will be forced to place different device types into different collections.*

Comment: Hi, I would like to collect different devices in one collection. ranging from hard drives details, networking interface details, Processor details etc.  Each device comes with its own customised methods.  Is this possible? Otherwise, I may be forced to create different collections for different classes as you suggested.